# Traits of an intelligent & civilized species that lives under a red dwarf star?

Tags: planets, xenobiology

More details -- their planet is very bigger than Earth, has stronger gravity than Earth's, it has 2 moons, it's not tidally locked, and they're supposed to have evolved from social obligate carnivore ambush predator ancestors. I hope that's enough info. Will edit to give more if needed.

Comment: If it's around a red dwarf but not close enough to be tidally-locked, I'd guess this world is very cold, right? A species adapted to navigating a frozen tundra is very different than one adapted for forests or deserts

Answer (score 1):

Based on your limited description traits would include:

- social units of pack or family members for living/hunting together, a standard household would be larger than a human one.
- 2 moons either mean that the tide on the planet would be stronger, or not noticeable depending on size and position. So their lives/culture would be heavily influenced or not at all depending on which.
- being ambush predators would mean that they have a means of camouflage, and that they have evolved with good eyesight and larger teeth.
- their society would develop a respect for strength, with perhaps an alpha male or female as a leader.

hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Social units of family member of humans were larger than now in not so distant past. In Paleolithic times it was around 20-30 individuals in a family group. It was convenient and sometimes required for survival, no less no more. And only the Neolithic Revolution have messed with this traditional social structure, just about 7-10 thsnd years ago. So its somewhat speculative to predict household structure of a civilised creature. It may have nothing common with the lifestyle their ancestors practiced decamilleniums ago.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in a series of novels by Paul Andersen "The Space Merchant". One of those novels covers exactly that topic - civilization developed in a red dwarf star system. Dont remember which novel exactly, I've read it too long ago.
That's what I can remember for sure. The perception of light by those creatures was extremely shifted comparing to human's. They could see in infrared, but could be easily blinded by yellow or blue light, whereas humans are used to yellow light and can barely see anything in natural sunlight of a red dwarf.